# Why does 1+++2 = 3?

Tags: python, evaluation, operator-precedence

How does Python evaluate the expression `1+++2`?

How many ever `+` I put in between, it is printing `3` as the answer. Please can anyone explain this behavior

And for `1--2` it is printing `3` and for `1---2` it is printing `-1`

Comment: So does that mean there are no increment operators in python?

Comment: To increment a variable i in python: i += 1

Comment: -1: The question makes a huge number of assumptions about ++ and --; things which are answered directly in http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/expressions.html

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your expression is the same as:

```
1+(+(+2))
```

Any numeric expression can be preceded by `-` to make it negative, or `+` to do nothing (the option is present for symmetry). With negative signs:

```
1-(-(2)) = 1-(-2)
         = 1+2
         = 3
```

and

```
1-(-(-2)) = 1-(2)
          = -1
```

I see you clarified your question to say that you come from a C background. In Python, there are no increment operators like `++` and `--` in C, which was probably the source of your confusion. To increment or decrement a variable `i` or `j` in Python use this style:

```
i += 1
j -= 1
```

Comment: Btw: That was a design decision from the Python creators. It should exactly prohibit writing such indetermined code like i+++j.

Answer (score 15):

The extra +'s are not incrementors (like ++a or a++ in c++).  They are just showing that the number is positive.

There is no such ++ operator.  There is a unary + operator and a unary - operator though.  The unary + operator has no effect on its argument. The unary - operator negates its operator or mulitplies it by -1.

```
+1
```

-> 1

```
++1
```

-> 1

This is the same as +(+(1))

```
   1+++2
```

-> 3
Because it's the same as 1 + (+(+(2))

Likewise you can do --1 to mean - (-1)  which is +1.

```
  --1
```

-> 1

For completeness there is no * unary opeartor.  So *1 is an error.  But there is a ** 
operator which is power of, it takes 2 arguments.

```
 2**3
```

-> 8

Answer (score 4):

1+(+(+2)) = 3

1 - (-2) = 3

1 - (-(-2)) = -1

Answer (score 4):

Trying [Unary Plus and Unary minus](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-operations):

> The unary - (minus) operator yields the negation of its numeric argument.
>
> The unary + (plus) operator yields its numeric argument unchanged.

```
>>> +2
2
>>> ++2
2
>>> +++2
2
>>> -2
-2
>>> --2
2
>>> ---2
-2
>>> 1+(++2)
3
```

Comment: but I am getting the result 3 for 1+++++++++++++2 also

Comment: No sweat: 1+(+(+(+(+(+(+(+(+(+(+(+(+2))))))))))))
12 +'s are unary - see Greg Hewgill's reply.

Answer (score 1):

Think it as 1 + (+1*(+1*2))). The first + is operator and following plus signs are sign of second operand (= 2).

Just like 1---2 is same as 1 - -(-(2)) or 1- (-1*(-1*(2))

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's being parsed as, the first + as a binary operation (add), and the rest as unary operations (make positive).

```
 1 + (+(+2))
```